# Laravel giving CORS error just for one route/controller

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

**Note: Edit at the bottom of this question**

I am having a very strange problem and Im starting to pull my hair out on this one. I am using Angular and Laravel 5.4.

I am using [Barryvdh\Cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) and it is working perfectly. However for some reason I am getting the following error for just one controller and nothing else!

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://www.example.com/packing?data_type=prealert&shipment_ref=1.
>   (Reason: missing token 'access-control-allow-headers' in CORS header
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).

This only happens with `packing`.

Here is my route (I have ommitted lots of other lines just for ease of reading):

```
    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::group([ 'middleware' => 'cors'], function()
    {

        // works
        Route::resource('prealert', 'PrealertController');

        // doesnt work
        Route::resource('packing', 'PackingController');

        // works
        Route::resource('shipping', 'ShippingController');

    });
```

I am comparing the two controllers below, as you can see they are the exact same (I think??).

Yet if I change

```
Route::resource('packing', 'PackingController');
```

to

```
Route::resource('packing', 'PrealertController');
```

It works fine.

I am assuming it is nothing from the AngularJS side because I have been able to narrow it down to simply that line, i.e. It works when I simply use another controller even if the code is the same.

Here is my `PackingController` (Http/Controllers/PackingController.php)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\PublishPackingRequest;
use Mockery\CountValidator\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use DB;
use Auth;


class PackingController extends Controller {

    public function index( ) {

        die('test');

    }

}
```

And my `PrealertController` (Http/Controllers/PrealertController.php)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\PublishPrealertRequest;
use Mockery\CountValidator\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Auth;
use DB;

class PrealertController extends Controller {


    public function index() {
        die('test');
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

So it gets even stranger, I duplicated my PackingController.php to a file called AnotherController.php and changed my route line to the following...

```
Route::resource('packing', 'AnotherController');
```

I also changed the class name to AnotherController

And even that worked! Maybe I should just try deleting the file

Comment: My guess would be some error is occuring in the controller, thus resulting in an error response and the error response isn't properly using CORS.

Comment: By doing a die(), are you not returning a proper http response? Have it return something or echo out Laravel's Response object

Comment: I dont think thats the issue becuase I am getting the `test` response from the working controllers. Also Angular sends an `OPTIONS` request first before sending the `GET` request, and for any controller that is not `PackingController` its getting as far as the `GET` but not so for that one

Comment: If you remove the PublishPackingRequest use statement (assuming there's no code using that class), do you still get the same error?

Comment: No but weirdly when I duplicated the controller as per my edit above I did have to create a new Request File as I was getting a Laravel error that it could not find PublishPackingRequest class. Yet when I renamed the file and renamed the class name etc to PublishPackinngRequest (extra n) the new file worked again. There is something about the work `Packing` that is causing problems. I am trying to see have I duplicated something but no luck yet

Comment: also to answer your question directly. I did remove it also, I even stripped down the class to almost nothing yet still the same error but only happening with `PackingController`.

Comment: It could be a permission issue on the class. Php errors should be on or you can check your php log. And maybe even do backend cache clearing if there's that

Comment: But if the above is the case I think you can see the page response in your browser's network requests which would be an obvious error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your controller might be stuck in a namespace autoload caching? I would try the following to resolve it, start by

```
composer -o dump-autoload
```

Then do a route cache refresh

```
php artisan route:cache
```

And then finally check if the route actually exists by using

```
php artisan route:list
```

I would also check if you can see the CORS middle ware is being applied to the route as you are not using it as a global middleware. It should come up like the "*oauth,api.company,api.user*" under the middleware section in the picture below[image]

If this doesn't fix the issue then I would check the controller's Camel casing is in proper order matching it from the Actions section is the route:list

Answer (score 0):

In order for the package to work, the request has to be a valid CORS request and needs to include an "Origin" header.

When an error occurs, the middleware isn't run completely. So when this happens, you won't see the actual result, but will get a CORS error instead.

Check that your action work without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue, all of my routes worked but one, and I knew that the route and its controller worked properly since I tested it with Postman. What was actually happening is that my Angular (5) automatically set the request type to OPTIONS for some reason (I was sending a JSON). Changing that to POST resolved the issue for me, I did it by sending FormData as per all of my other POST requests in the app. **Always check your networking tab**.